# How to convert some functions from an Activity to a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I try to convert my activity to a fragment, but I have some problems that occurs. 
The layout in the HomeFragment is null, so it occurs a crash...

**My HomeActivity:**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //the layout on which you are working
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);

    final ConstraintLayout layout2 = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout2.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
...
```

**My HomeFragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

        //the layout on which you are working
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);

        final ConstraintLayout layout2 = (ConstraintLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = layout2.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                 layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace the `getActivity()` with `view` which you inflate above.

Comment: share the crash log

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous Oh yes! Thank you! I was blind. You can put it in the answer, I will tick your answer.

Comment: Thanks @ΩlostA, I've post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your `getActivity()` calls with your inflated view.

**Before**

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);
```

**After**

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);
```